# Image on principled

Tags: materials, node-editor, image

I want to place a single logo on the bottom half of the bin, whilst preserving the color of principled. What am i doing wrong here?
[image]

Comment: Relevant: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mixing a diffuse with a principled with a constant .5 factor. I would highly suggest using a Color Mixer Node instead, using the alpha channel, and feeding it directly into the principled color.
[image: Mix Node Setup]

Comment: That makes no sense.